# How to read time-series data from audio (.wav) file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time-series, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I want to read the time-series data and sampling rate of the .wav file which will be uploaded via the **React UI**. Is there something equivalent to
`signaldata,samplingrate = librosa.load('sample.wav')`
[reference](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.load.html)

**Librosa** is a python audio processing library. I have tried to use Web Audio API but I'm unable to understand the implementation.

Thanks in advance!